# I am having trouble adding react to html

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

So I wanted to add react cdn links to my html, but nothing is happening. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I looked up so many tutorials and examples and I even copied other examples with the same cdn links and they work just fine. But for some reason I can't get my project to render.

Here is my code for the html:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Random Quote Machine</title>
    <script
      src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"
      crossorigin
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"
      crossorigin
    ></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="root"></div>

     <script src="./script.js" type="text/babel"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Javascript file:

```
const quotes= [
    {
      quote:
        "Life is too short and sweet to be spent by cribbing and complaining about things. Here are some random quotes about the most wonderful gift that we've got",
      author: " Life"
    },
  {
   quote: "Programming is not a science. Programming is a craft.",
  author: "Richard Stallman"  
  },
  {
    quote: "Most good programmers do programming not because they expect to get paid or get adulation by the public, but because it is fun to program.",
    author: "Linus Torvalds"
  },
   {
    quote: "In real open source, you have the right to control your own destiny",
    author: "Linus Torvalds"
  },
  {
  quote: "We don't make mistakes; we just have happy accidents.",
    
    author: "Bob Ross"
  }
  
  ];

class Quote extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
   quote: '----',
   author: '----'
   };
  
  this.handleChange=this.handleChange.bind(this);
}
  
  handleChange(){
    let i= Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length)
    this.setState({
      quote: quotes[i].quote,
      author: quotes[i].author
    });
  }
  
 render() {
  return (
    <div>
    <div id="quote-box">
      <div id="text"> 
      <button id="new-quote" onClick={this.handleChange}>Click Me</button>
      <p>Quote: {this.state.quote}</p>
        <div id="author">
        <p>Author: {this.state.author}</p>
           
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
     </div>
  );
 }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Quote />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Here is the error of my console: [image]

Comment: Works fine on my end

Comment: Do you see any error in the console?

Comment: Yeah I just added the image

Comment: you need a localhost web server

Comment: I think you are trying to open the HTML file directly rather then running a dev server

Comment: Okay so I can just run it with a simple node.js server? Also, why can't I open the html file directly when I was able to do it with other examples I followed online? I'm bit of a newbie in web dev :b

Comment: @CodeNewbie if you are using vscode you can use the live server extension. https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer